# Wrong arrangement of Table

Tags: tables, graphics

my Page starts with a picture then some text and after that i created a table. But after the build, the table is in front of the picture. At the beginning of the page...

```
\newpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{./supply}
\caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}

Text....
Text....
Text....

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Pin & Beschreibung \\ \hline
Conn2.1 & Positive Versorgungsspannung\\ \hline
Conn2.2 & Ground\\ \hline
Conn2.3 & Negative Versorgungsspannung\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{other caption}
\end{table}

\newpage
```

Comment: Try with `\begin{table}[htb]`.

Comment: simply remove the ht in the options of the figure -- see the answer below

Comment: what does this ht mean?

Comment: See also: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)

Comment: @Zarko that worked! thanks

Comment: Meanwhile I wrote answer to your question. If you liked it and if it solve your problem on the best way, you can accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me spell out my comment ... If you not specify position of floats (`figure`, `table`) they will float to the top of page, so your case you only need to specify positioning for table too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht] % <---
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image-duck}%{./supply}
\caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htb] % <---
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Pin & Beschreibung \\ \hline
Conn2.1 & Positive Versorgungsspannung\\ \hline
Conn2.2 & Ground\\ \hline
Conn2.3 & Negative Versorgungsspannung\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{other caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details about float positioning and meaning of (positions) specifier `h` (here) , `t` (top), `b` (bottome) `p` (page); see comprehensive description in the Frank Mittelbach answer [float positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). BTW, it is recommended that you use `h` in pair with `t` or `b` etc, since otherwise can happen that float will be pushed to the end of document, if in the page after its inserting will not be enough space for it placement.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%1inch=25,4mm
%\titlelabel{{\hspace*{1cm}\makebox[1cm][l]{\thetitle}}}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \newpage
    
    \begin{figure}[]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{./supply}
        \caption{Some Caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    Text....
    Text....
    Text....
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            Pin & Beschreibung \\ \hline
            Conn2.1 & Positive Versorgungsspannung\\ \hline
            Conn2.2 & Ground\\ \hline
            Conn2.3 & Negative Versorgungsspannung\\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{other caption}
    \end{table}
    
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%1inch=25,4mm
%\titlelabel{{\hspace*{1cm}\makebox[1cm][l]{\thetitle}}}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \newpage
    
    \begin{figure}[]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{./supply}
        \caption{Some Caption}
    \end{figure}
    
    Text....
    Text....
    Text....
    
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            Pin & Beschreibung \\ \hline
            Conn2.1 & Positive Versorgungsspannung\\ \hline
            Conn2.2 & Ground\\ \hline
            Conn2.3 & Negative Versorgungsspannung\\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{other caption}
    \end{table}
    
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But i want the Table be under the text

Comment: please see the edit above